# Select most recent entry within a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the most recent value for `RESULT` during a group by, but i can't seem to figure out how i can get it done successfully.

Here is the table data for quiz_result:
[image]

Here is my current SQL statement and the result:

```
SELECT quiz_result.ID_EVALUATION,
       quiz_result.ID_QUIZ_QUESTION,
       quiz_result.ID_USER,
       quiz_result.RESULT as RECENT_RESULT,
       max(CREATED_DATE)  as RECENT_ATTEMPT_DATE,
       "-----"  as NEXT_REPITITION,
       COUNT(quiz_result.RESULT) as TOTAL,
       sum(case when quiz_result.RESULT = 'false' then 1 else 0 end) AS FAILED_ATTEMPTS,
       sum(case when quiz_result.RESULT = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) AS SUCESS_ATTEMPTS
FROM p2.quiz_result
GROUP BY ID_USER,ID_QUIZ_QUESTION
ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC;
```

[image]

I thought the `ORDER BY CREATED_DATE` would sort the result before the group by, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

If you compare `RESULT` from the first image, with the column `RECENT_RESULT` in the second image, it's clear that `RECENT_RESULT` should have been '*false*' if it worked as intended.

I can't seem to figure out how I can do this, so some help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked the query, and added a sub-query to get the information.

```
SELECT QR1.ID_EVALUATION,
   QR1.ID_QUIZ_QUESTION,
   QR1.ID_USER,
   (SELECT QR2.RESULT FROM quiz_result QR2 WHERE QR1.ID_QUIZ_QUESTION = QR2.ID_QUIZ_QUESTION AND QR1.ID_USER = QR2.ID_USER ORDER BY QR2.CREATED_DATE DESC limit 1 ) as RECENT_RESULT,
   max(QR1.CREATED_DATE)  as RECENT_ATTEMPT_DATE,
   "-----"  as NEXT_REPITITION,
   COUNT(QR1.RESULT) as TOTAL,
   sum(case when QR1.RESULT = 'false' then 1 else 0 end) AS FAILED_ATTEMPTS,
   sum(case when QR1.RESULT = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) AS SUCESS_ATTEMPTS
FROM p2.quiz_result QR1 
GROUP BY QR1.ID_USER,QR1.ID_QUIZ_QUESTION
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY <your sorting column> DESC;
```

Order by is applied after group by.

Comment: i actually had a DESC on it, it just got lost during writing. But If "order by" is applied after the group by, then i need to do this differently i think.

Comment: @MetalMike you are also selecting non aggregated columns that are not used in the GROUP BY clause. This may lead to undetermined results.